# What does " I"ll have you" mean?

Tags: meaning

> I'll soon have you all strong enough to face anything.

What does *I will have you* mean, in that sentence?

Comment: *To have you all strong enough* means *to cause them to be very strong*

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Better still, _to help them to become stronger_ (perhaps by feeding them well or training them in fitness, depending on the context).

Comment: Compare "The comic *had* the audience rolling in the aisles."  or "The doctors and nurses said they would *have* him back on his feet in no time."

Comment: Quote posted without source. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it means that he will cause them to become whatever. In this case, cause them to become strong. Perhaps through his training program, or moral suasion.

Perhaps I should not that when I saw the title of your question, I thought you were asking something very different. "I'll have you" by itself is normally understood to mean that I will dominate or possess you sexually.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the causative structures.

**"to have someone do something"**,

It means *"to cause someone to do something by paying or persuading or helping or such similar ways.*"

Answer (score 1):

"*I'll have*" in this context means *I will cause to happen* or *I will arrange for*.

So, "*I'll soon have you all strong enough to face anything*" is a promise to help everybody become strong.

It does **not** necessarily mean you will cause someone else to do something. For example, a doctor might say "*we'll soon have you well*" which is a promise that *they* will make the patient better. But in the case of your example, it sounds like the person is promising to help others to achieve something, so there is probably work from both parties.